# How to mock a method of a third party package

Tags: unit-testing, go

I had a simple function which connects to mongoDB and create a new document. 
Now how do I mock the methods of the imported mongo package while unit testing.

Ive tried to mock GinContext by monkeypatching.

But unable to proceed with mocking the actual mongoClient as the package is imported.

```golang
func CreateUser(c GinContext) {
    var userdetail UserDetails
    binderr := c.ShouldBindJSON(&userdetail)
    fmt.Println(binderr)
    if binderr != nil {
        c.JSON(500, gin.H{
            "message": "Input payload not matching",
            "error":   binderr,
        })
        return
    }

    //-- Client if of type *mongo.Client. 

        //-- How do I mock the Client.Database, Client.Database.Connection

    collection := Client.Database("demo").Collection("users")
    ctx, err1 := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    if err1 != nil {
    }
    response, err2 := collection.InsertOne(ctx, userdetail)
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Println("Some error inserting the document")
    }
    fmt.Println(response.InsertedID)
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
        "message": "User created successfully",
    })
}
```

Expected: I should be able to mock or stub Client and provide dummy functionality. Just like in nodeJS we do

spyOn(Client,'Database').and.return(Something)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time I'm wondering "how to mock a method", this is mostly related to my code architecture. Not being able to test easily some code means, most of time, that the code is poorly designed and/or too coupled to the used libraries/frameworks. Here, you want to mock Mongo connection only because your code is too tightly related to Mongo (in the `CreateUser` function). Refactoring could help you to test your code (without any Mongo connection).

I've experienced that using interfaces and dependency injection simplifies
the testing process in Go, and clarifies the architecture. Here is my attempt to help you test your application.

#### Code refactoring

First, define what you want to do with an **interface**. Here, you're inserting users, so let's do a `UserInserter` interface, with a single method for now (`Insert`, to insert a single user) :

```golang
type UserInserter interface {
    Insert(ctx context.Context, userDetails UserDetails) (insertedID interface{}, err error)
}
```

In the code you have provided, you are only using the `insertedID`, so you probably only need it as output of this `Insert` method (and an optional error if something gone wrong). `insertedID` is defined as an `interface{}` here, but feel free to change to whatever you want.

Then, let's modify your `CreateUser` method and inject this `UserInserter` **as a parameter** :

```golang
func CreateUser(c *gin.Context, userInserter UserInserter) {
    var userdetail UserDetails
    binderr := c.ShouldBindJSON(&userdetail)
    fmt.Println(binderr)
    if binderr != nil {
        c.JSON(500, gin.H{
            "message": "Input payload not matching",
            "error":   binderr,
        })
        return
    }

    // this is the modified part
    insertedID, err2 := userInserter.Insert(c, userdetail)
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Println("Some error inserting the document")
    }
    fmt.Println(insertedID)

    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
        "message": fmt.Sprintf("User %s created successfully", insertedID),
    })
}
```

This method could be refactored but, to avoid any confusion, I will not touch it.

`userInserter.Insert(c, userdetail)` replaces here the Mongo dependency in this method by injecting `userInserter`.

You can now implement your `UserInserter` interface with the backend of your choice (Mongo in your case). Insertion into Mongo needs a `Collection` object (the collection we are inserting the user in), so let's add this as an **attribute** :

```golang
type MongoUserInserter struct {
    collection *mongo.Collection
}
```

Implementation of `Insert` method follows (call `InsertOne` method on `*mongo.Collection`) :

```golang
func (i MongoUserInserter) Insert(ctx context.Context, userDetails UserDetails) (insertedID interface{}, err error) {
    response, err := i.collection.InsertOne(ctx, userDetails)
    return response.InsertedID, err
}
```

This implementation could be in a separated package and should be tested separately.

Once implemented, you can use `MongoUserInserter` in your main application, where Mongo is the backend. `MongoUserInserter` is initialized in the main function, and injected in the `CreateUser` method. Router setup have been separated (also for testing purpose) :

```golang
func setupRouter(userInserter UserInserter) *gin.Engine {
    router := gin.Default()

    router.POST("/createUser", func(c *gin.Context) {
        CreateUser(c, userInserter)
    })

    return router
}

func main() {
    client, _ := mongo.NewClient()
    collection := client.Database("demo").Collection("users")
    userInserter := MongoUserInserter{collection: collection}

    router := setupRouter(userInserter)
    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

Note that if some day you want to change the backend, you will only
need to change the `userInserter` in the main function!

#### Tests

From a tests perspective, it is now easier to test because we can create a fake `UserInserter`, like :

```golang
type FakeUserInserter struct{}

func (_ FakeUserInserter) Insert(ctx context.Context, userDetails UserDetails) (insertedID interface{}, err error) {
    return userDetails.Name, nil
}
```

(I supposed here `UserDetails` have an attribute `Name`).

If you really want to mock this interface, you can take a look at [GoMock](https://github.com/golang/mock). In this case though, I'm not sure using a mock framework is required.

And now we can test our `CreateUser` method with a simple HTTP testing framework (see https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#testing), without needing a Mongo connection or mocking it.

```golang
import (
    "bytes"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestCreateUser(t *testing.T) {
    userInserter := FakeUserInserter{}
    router := setupRouter(userInserter)

    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    body := []byte(`{"name": "toto"}`)
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "/createUser", bytes.NewBuffer(body))
    router.ServeHTTP(w, req)

    assert.Equal(t, 200, w.Code)
    assert.Equal(t, `{"message":"User toto created successfully"}`, w.Body.String())
}
```

Note that this does not exempt to also test `Insert` method of `MongoUserInserter`, but separately : here, this test covers `CreateUser`, not the `Insert` method.

Comment: Thanks for the well descriptive solution. From what I've understood is, not to use the library or package directly, instead accept their functionality via function parameter as an interface, passed by the caller function. But doesn't that mean, for every library that we use in our code, we need an interface.

Comment: Actually, it's all about code design. Using interfaces is convenient to easily change implementation and for testing (fake implementation as you can see in my answer). But as you said, it can be quite painful to create interfaces for all external libraries structs. It's a trade-off you have to make. In that particular example, if you implement user deletion, user retrieval, ..., instead of creating 1 interface for each feature, you can define just 1 interface `UserHandler`. Remember also that mock libraries does not work with structs, so you'll have to define interfaces anyway for mocking.